# page sending by email

Tags: reporting-services

When I am trying to send the Report by using the IE option Page -> Send Page By Email. I am getting error.

```
    This page might not function correctly because either your browser does not support scripts or active scripting is disabled






Home > Report Project3 > Report1 
 Home | My Subscriptions | Site Settings | Help


 Your browser does not support scripts or has been configured not to allow scripts. 



Report Viewer Configuration Error 
The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file. Add <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type = "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, ReportingServicesWebUserInterface, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" /> to the system.web/httpHandlers section of the web.config file, or add <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, ReportingServicesWebUserInterface, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" /> to the system.webServer/handlers section for Internet Information Services 7 or later.
```

Comment: And why would someone want to close it without specifing the reason. Am I not allowed to ask SSRS questions here ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be browser related rather than code related. Seems like Internet Explorer's security settings are set to high. you can try out one thing

In Internet Explorer, go to Tools -> Internet Options -> Security Settings -> Internet and try enabling the checkboxs related to scripts or selecting Medium as the default security level.

What happens when you try to send a page via email is that, IE tries to open email client(outlook) on your machine with the help of some scripts. Seems like IE is running under high security which is preventing execution of scripts.

Hope this would help you.